# How to show that Choquet's theorem implies Krein Milman theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally convex topological vector space and $K$ a nonempty convex compact subset. Let the set of extreme points of $K$ be $K_e$.

Then Choquet's theorem says that for any $u \in K$, there is a probability measure $m_u$ on the closure $\bar{K_e}$ such that $l(u)=\int_\bar{K_e}l(e)dm_u(e)$ for any continuous linear functional $l$ on $X$.

Now, I need to show that this theorem implies $K$ being the closed convex hull of $K_e$. However, I cannot see how to proceed. The integral is essentially continuous. How do I extract the (discrete) convex combinations from the integral? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you try the (Hahn-Banach) separation theorem?

Comment: How do I apply the theorem? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: If $u\in K$ does not belong to the clocsed convex hull $C$ of the extremal points there is a continuous linear functional $\ell$ with $\ell(c)\le 1$ for $c\in C$ and $\ell(u)>1$. Since $m_u$ is a probability measure you get $\int_{K_e}\ell(x) dm_u(x) \le 1$.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your hint. Could you help me with another related problem I posted?